# wxWidgets Seg fault on close

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, wxwidgets

My files look something like so:

main.cpp

```
...
bool SyncApp::OnInit(){
    SetTopWindow(new syncWindow(_("(S)FTP Automatic Sync")));
    GetTopWindow()->Show(true);
    return true;
}
...
```

syncwindow.h

```
#include <wx/wx.h>

class syncWindow : public wxFrame {
    public:
        syncWindow(wxString title) : wxFrame(NULL, -1, title)  { initialize(); }
    private:
        void initialize();
        wxTextCtrl * serverEntry;
};
```

syncwindow.cpp

```
void syncWindow::initialize(){
    serverEntry = new wxTextCtrl(this, wxID_ANY);

    this->AddChild(serverEntry);
}
```

For whatever reason whenever I close the window I get a segfault. If I don't add the serverEntry as a child to the window I don't get a segfault. I don't see why this is doing such a thing. I'm on CentOS 6, g++ 4.7 and wxGTK 2.8. Does anyone have any idea or a hint as to why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you specified the parent window when constructing your child, the link is already present and calling `this->AddChild(serverEntry);` will cause double free or similar error when you close the window. http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.8/wx_wxwindow.html#wxwindowaddchild

> **wxWindow::AddChild**
>
> Adds a child window. This is called automatically by window creation
>   functions so should not be required by the application programmer.
>
> Notice that this function is mostly internal to wxWidgets and
>   shouldn't be called by the user code.

Comment: Correct, `AddChild()` should never be called actually, whether you specified the parent when creating the window or not (then you need to either call `Create()` passing it the parent or `Reparent()`). Its [documentation](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_window.html#abf60159278059a5bb397eb8647227bb3) even states as much.